# View Slideshow of multiple images of a single product

Tags: drupal-7, slideshow, drupal-views, product

How to show slideshow of multiple images of a product. I am able to make slideshow of the images of a content type like Product Display which displays me the images of all the products.([Read here for more](http://www.bentedder.com/create-an-easy-jquery-slideshow-in-drupal-7/comment-page-1/#comment-5501)). But I want to show images of a single product. Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 1):

[Field Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) should do it for you.